# Php Regex: How to make a submatch optional if is at the end of subject

Tags: php, regex

```
$text = 'something here *ls67 another thing'; // match
$text2 = 'something here *ls67. another thing'; // match
$text3 = 'something here  another thing *ls67.'; // match
$text3 = 'something here  another thing *ls67'; // doesn't match (and i need to match this)

$pattern = '|^(.*)?(\*[0-9a-zA-Z_-]{3,15})([^0-9a-zA-Z_-])+(.*)?$|i';
```

I've tried this pattern but it generates an error:

```
$pattern = '|^(.*)?(\*[0-9a-zA-Z_-]{3,15})([^0-9a-zA-Z_-]|$)+(.*)?$|i'; // Unknown modifier '$'
// and
$pattern = '|^(.*)?(\*[0-9a-zA-Z_-]{3,15})(([^0-9a-zA-Z_-])+|$)(.*)?$|i'; // same error
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using `|` as your [delimiter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php), you need to escape any `|`'s that appear in the pattern (or you could change it to a character that doesn't appear in your pattern, such as `#`. Since you introduced unescaped `|`'s in your second block of code, PCRE tries to take the characters following (staring with `$`) as [modifiers](http://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html), hence the error.

This should work:

```
$pattern = '#^(.*)?(\*[0-9a-zA-Z_-]{3,15})([^0-9a-zA-Z_-]+(.*)?|$)#i';
```